# two unrelated queries in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the output of that two queries with separate columns in one query result

I have these queries

```
select Name_UM  as EMPLOYEE  from Universal_Master2 WHERE Module_UM='EMPL'
select Name_UM  as BRANCH from Universal_Master2    WHERE Module_UM='Branch'
```

My output result Like this

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that in a query?

Comment: So that I can only do one loop to fetch datas.

Comment: I Have One doubt  in 8 Employee show and 6 branch how to maintain each row

Comment: They don't have equal rows because the two columns are unrelated. I just want to get the two columns in one query result.

Comment: if record show one employee in two branches it's problem for you

Comment: That employees and branches are different, they don't have any relation at all. I just wanted the result of the two.

Comment: As others have indicated this is a bad idea. Pairing unrelated rows in two tables mean extra work for the DBMS compared to reading them one by one. Though I don't know your code I'm having a hard time believing that it will be better and more understandable than doing one loop over each table and handle the pairing in the application.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Lennart doing one loop on each table is better. But I'm having problem doing while loop inside while loop. I only got 1 row result when I'm doing that. I'm using php in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select EMPLOYEE, BRANCH from (
select row_number() over (order by Name_UM) as Pos, Name_UM as EMPLOYEE from Universal_Master2 where Module_UM='EMPL'
) as a
full join ( 
select row_number() over (order by Name_UM) as Pos, Name_UM as BRANCH from Universal_Master2 where Module_UM='Branch'
) as b
on a.Pos = b.Pos
```

I assume that the columns are not related.

Answer (score 5):

Use row_number for each query and join them by this row_number.
(for me, your request is not logical but ...)

```
SELECT e.employee
       ,b.branch
FROM
(
select Name_UM as employee 
  ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Name_UM ORDER BY Name_UM) AS rn_emp
from Universal_Master2 
where Module_UM='empl'
)E
FULL JOIN
(
select Name_UM as branch 
  ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Name_UM ORDER BY Name_UM) AS rn_branch
from Universal_Master2 
where Module_UM='Branch'
)B
on E.rn_emp= B.rn_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select X.employee,Y.branch from
(select Name_UM as employee from Universal_Master2 where Module_UM='empl') as X,
(select Name_UM as branch from Universal_Master2 where Module_UM='Branch') as Y
```

Comment: The result here repeats many times. Two queries are unrelated.

Comment: It does what was requested though. That's one way to interpret it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below approaches

```
 WHERE Module_UM in ('Branch','empl')
```

or

```
select ist query
union
select second query
```

Comment: I want the result to be in 2 different columns. How to query it?

Comment: can you share your current result and expected result

Comment: The query result is fine but i wanted to separate the branch and employees in two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE,BRANCH.BRANCH  from
    (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null))rn, Name_UM  as EMPLOYEE  from Universal_Master2 WHERE Module_UM='EMPL') EMPLOYEE
full outer join 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null))rn,Name_UM  as BRANCH from Universal_Master2    WHERE Module_UM='Branch')
    BRANCH 
   on EMPLOYEE.rn =BRANCH.rn
```

**OUTPUT with some sample data:**

```
EMPLOYEE    BRANCH
abc         efg
ert         gtr
rt          yr
```

Comment: The result here repeats many times. Two queries are unrelated, kindly see https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbvNh.png

Answer (score 0):

please check it :

```
select 
   (CASE Module_UM WHEN 'EMPL' THEN Name_UM
   ELSE NULL END) as EMPLOYEE,  
(CASE Module_UM WHEN 'Branch' THEN Name_UM
   ELSE NULL END) as BRANCH,    
from Universal_Master2 UM
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get rid of null results? I want to remove null in rows.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result as expected follow the below steps:

```
1) Add column beside both tables as rownumber
2) Insert or Update on column rownumber using function ROWNUMBER()
3) After that join both tables using that rownumber column.
```